# Simple doctrine query using symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to build a basic query using symfony and doctrine. The query will return a User and all the jobs they are working on. From the two tables 'User' and UserDetails (Contains User_id and Job_id). User is mapped to userdetails correctly as one- many.

my query is

```
SELECT   userdetails, u FROM TestBundle:User 
join userdetails.u
```

As user is a field in userdetails, but userdetails isn't a member of users the following query doesn't work. Is there any way to write this so the result will look like User.userDetails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
SELECT
  u, ud
FROM 
  TestBundle:User u
JOIN //LEFT JOIN if you want also users without UserDetails
  TestBundle:UserDetails ud
WITH
  u.id = ud.user_id
```

of course your variables (like `ud.user_id`) could vary but we don't have enough informations to work on so we have to guess

Comment: Thanks for the help, had to change ON to WITH to get it to work. It still put userdetails as a seperate row, but does what i need. Cheers

Comment: @user3248331: yes, I was into "autopilot" mode and wrote with a typo; updated. Dont' forget to accept the answer if this works for you.